# How to disable selection of tab bar items - swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller

I have an application that has two UIViewcontroller embedded in a UITabBarcontroller.  When I am in UIViewController-1, i would like to press a button that disables all item selection of the tab bar.  My effort is below but I am not sure how to complete the code ...

[image]

When I am in the 'Folders' UIViewController I would like to disable the selection of any tab bar item:

```
 class Folders: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate{

 ...
 // DISABLE TAB BAR ITEMS
 func disable (){
    let tabBarItemsArray = self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items
    tabBarItemsArray[0].enabled = false // THIS BIT OF CODE IS NOT RECOGNIZED BY XCODE
  }
 ...
 }
```

Comment: there ts a UITabBraControllerDelegate method for that. tabBarController(_:shouldSelect:). https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uitabbarcontrollerdelegate/1621166-tabbarcontroller

Answer (score 3):

`tabBarItemsArray` is optional, its type is `[UITabBarItem]?`.

You could initially force unwrap it: `tabBarItemsArray![0]`, but the right way is to use `if let` construct:

```
if let tabBarItemsArray = tabBarController.tabBar.items {
    tabBarItemsArray[0].isEnabled = false
}
```

or:

```
guard let tabBarItemsArray = tabBarController.tabBar.items else {
    fatalError("Error")
}
let item = tabBarItemsArray[0]
item.isEnabled = false
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do that using single line of code. Please check following code.

> You can execute this from any controller.

```
self.navigationController?.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![0].isEnabled = false
```

---

## Another way

You can define NotificationCenter observer to achieve. Please check following code. *In TabBar Controller file.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(disableTab(notification:)), name: Notification.Name("disableTab"), object: nil)
}

@objc func disableTab(notification: Notification) {
    self.TabBarItem.isEnabled = false
}
```

> **Fire from anywhere as following...**

```
NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name("disableTab"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to disable one tabbar item at once then this is for disabling the first one:

```
guard let tabbars = self.tabBar.items else {
                  return
              }
              tabbars[0].isEnabled = false
```

but if you want them all to be disabled at once then this is the one to be implemented:

```
 self.tabBar.items?.map{$0.isEnabled = false}
```